# Motion Computing m1400 - Wacom Touchscreen not recognized

Tags: 12.04, wacom

Got myself a Motion Computing (basically Gateway) m1400 tablet PC a year ago, and it's been a running project for a while now.

I've been struggling with this machine since day one, but after a lot of head banging, I got a clean install of Xubuntu 12.04.

The only remaining problem is that Ubuntu does not seem to recognize the Wacom digitizer screen.

```
collin@Molly:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 82852/82855 GM/GME/PM/GMV Processor to I/O Controller (rev 02)
00:00.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation 82852/82855 GM/GME/PM/GMV Processor to I/O Controller (rev 02)
00:00.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation 82852/82855 GM/GME/PM/GMV Processor to I/O Controller (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82852/855GM Integrated Graphics Device (rev 02)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation 82852/855GM Integrated Graphics Device (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-M) USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 83)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801DBM (ICH4-M) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 03)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801DBM (ICH4-M) IDE Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.5 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.6 Modem: Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) AC'97 Modem Controller (rev 03)
02:00.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Texas Instruments TSB43AB22A IEEE-1394a-2000 Controller (PHY/Link) [iOHCI-Lynx]
02:01.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+ (rev 10)
02:02.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 2200BG [Calexico2] Network Connection (rev 05)
02:04.0 CardBus bridge: ENE Technology Inc CB1410 Cardbus Controller (rev 01)
```

So after some googling, I figured my problem was I needed to install the [Linux Wacom Driver](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/linuxwacom/index.php?title=Main_Page). Ultimately, I discovered that these drivers are now *included* in 12.04, but regardless, I tried to compile them and got the following after running ./configure:

```
No package 'xorg-server' found
No package 'xproto' found
No package 'xext' found
No package 'kbproto' found
No package 'inputproto' found
No package 'randrproto' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables XORG_CFLAGS
and XORG_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

So I am again stumped. I didn't think this would be a problem, as the digitzer worked out of the box in a previous 10.04 install, but I've spent hours trying to find a solution this time around.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar trouble with a motion computing M1300 and it almost drive me mad.
You asked about two months ago, and although this answer may be arriving late, I hope it helps anyway.

Soooo here we go:

First thing first:
**You don't have to install any driver.** It's already installed in your Xubuntu 12.04. You just have to configure the stylus in Xorg.conf.
take a look at this post:

http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1840911.html

The solution its at the end where it says :

---

```
I also tried installing and patching inputattach but that doesn't seem to work
   either...
   Well that argues it is ISDV4. I'd feel better if we saw an ISDV4 product ID though.  
   Good you checked that out.


   OK, this assumes your xorg.conf is empty. If instead there is something in it, 
   probably to do with your Intel integrated video chipset, please post it. You'll 
   still add the Wacom sections but we'll need to change the "ServerLayout":
  

   Section "InputDevice"
   Driver "wacom"
   Identifier "stylus"
   Option "Device" "/dev/ttyS4"
   Option "Type" "stylus"
   Option "Button2" "3"
   EndSection

   Section "InputDevice"
   Driver "wacom"
   Identifier "eraser"
   Option "Device" "/dev/ttyS4"
   Option "Type" "eraser"
   EndSection

   Section "ServerLayout"
   Identifier "X.org Configured"
   InputDevice "stylus"
   InputDevice "eraser"
   EndSection
Before you change anything if you have an xorg.conf first back it up. Backing up and restoring xorg.conf from the command line is discussed in Old serial tablet driver part II. on "HOW TO Set Up a Wacom Serial Tablet".

Use:

gksudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

All you have to do is:

1. Type  "dmesg | grep ttyS" in a Terminal window.
   You showd get something like:

   " 0:11: **ttyS0** at I/O 0x3f8 (irq=4) is a 16550A"

   Note that the "ttyS0" value may be different for you.

   Write down the "ttySX" obtained.
2. Create,or modify it if it already exists, a xorg.conf file as indicated in the
   post replacing "ttyS4" with the "ttySX" value obtained in step 1.
3. Reboot and enjoy.

In my particular case, the problem was that I assumed the stylus was not working because it was too old for new distros.
The result of doing a "dmesg | grep ttyS", at command line, lead me to think the wacom tablet model of my M1300 was an old serial ISD4. This kind of wacom tablets are not supported by new ubuntu ditros. But reading that post I discovered that Motion Computing M1300 and M1400 have ISDV4 wacom tablets that are fully supported but need to be configured in xorg.conf file.

Comment: Hi, I've since sold the m1400, and bought an HP 2740p instead. Sorry to make you write all that up for nothing, and I really appreciate the detail you went in to.

I suppose the joke's on me now though, since I'm having calibration troubles with the 2740p.

Thanks again Sergio.